# How can I get all the object inside an object which is present inside an array and add the result into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

I am struggling with an issue that is bugging me a lot. I am not good with JSON data manipulation.

So the issue is I have an Array of multiple Object which contain some data, Now inside these objects, I have another array of objects which I want

the JSON looks something like this-

```
const data = [{
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4,
  d: [{
    e: 5,
    f: 4,
    g: 6,
  }, {
    h: 5,
    i: 4,
    j: 6,
  }]
}, {
  a: 11,
  b: 31,
  c: 42,
  d: [{
    e: 54,
    f: 46,
    g: 62,
  }, {
    h: 55,
    i: 42,
    j: 64,
  }]
}]
```

Now What I want is an Array which holds the following data

```
const d = [{
  e: 5,
  f: 4,
  g: 6,
}, {
  h: 5,
  i: 4,
  j: 6,
}, {
  e: 54,
  f: 46,
  g: 62,
}, {
  h: 55,
  i: 42,
  j: 64,
}]
```

I tried mapping over the data but I always end up with an array that look

```
const data = [
  [{
    e: 5,
    f: 4,
    g: 6,
  }, {
    h: 5,
    i: 4,
    j: 6,
  }],
  [{
    e: 54,
    f: 46,
    g: 62,
  }, {
    h: 55,
    i: 42,
    j: 64,
  }]

]
```

Not sure what am i doing wrong. need some help

Comment: `I tried ...` no code to show you tried anything ... why are you posting data as snippets anyway, and not even bothering to format (fixed it for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the `data` and then loop over the `data.d` again to get all of the required data. For each of the data, you push it into another array that you will later use.

```js
const data = [{a:2,b:3,c:4,d:[{e:5,f:4,g:6,},{h:5,i:4,j:6,}]},{a:11,b:31,c:42,d:[{e:54,f:46,g:62,},{h:55,i:42,j:64,}]}]
let result = [];
data.forEach(d => d.d.forEach(dd => result.push(dd)));
console.log(result);
```